Это сравнение кажется непреднамеренным, поскольку типы "string" и "() => React.JSX.Element" не перекрываются
Мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог в профиле менять пароль, сделал экран с вводом пароля и попытлася сохранить введенные числа в переменные auth. В итоге при импорте его на экран блокировки код выдает ошибку:

[{
"resource": "/Users/artemmedvedev/Desktop/SpinEx-App/app/(modals)/lock.tsx",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "2367",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Это сравнение кажется непреднамеренным, поскольку типы "string" и "() => React.JSX.Element" не перекрываются.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 29,
"startColumn": 11,
"endLineNumber": 29,
"endColumn": 33
}]

код экрана нового пароля:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import * as Haptics from 'expo-haptics';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withRepeat, withSequence, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const Page = () => {

    const [code, setCode] = useState<number[]>([]);
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState<string>('');
    const codeLength = Array(6).fill(0);
    const router = useRouter();
  
    const offset = useSharedValue(0);
    const style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      return {
        transform: [{ translateX: offset.value }],
      }
    });
  
    const simpleDialog = () => {
      Alert.alert("Изменение пароля", "Пароль успешно изменен", [{ text: "OK" }], {
        cancelable: true,
      });
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (code.length === 6) {
        setAuth(code.join(''));
        simpleDialog();
        router.replace('/');
        console.log(code.join(''));
      }
    }, [code]);
  
    const onNumberPress = (number: number) => {
      Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
      setCode([...code, number]);
    };
  
    const numberBackspace = () => {
      Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
      setCode(code.slice(0, -1));
    };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.greeting}>Придумайте пароль</Text>

      <Animated.View style={[styles.codeView, style]}>
        {codeLength.map((_, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={[styles.codeEmpty,
            {
              backgroundColor: code[index] ? '#3D38ED' : '#D8DCE2',
            }]} />
        ))}
      </Animated.View>

      <View style={styles.numbersView}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          {[1, 2, 3].map((number) => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text key={number} style={styles.number} onPress={() => onNumberPress(number)}>
              {number}
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          {[4, 5, 6].map((number) => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text key={number} style={styles.number} onPress={() => onNumberPress(number)}>
              {number}
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          {[7, 8, 9].map((number) => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text key={number} style={styles.number} onPress={() => onNumberPress(number)}>
              {number}
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>

        <View style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
          <View>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onNumberPress(0)}>
            <Text style={styles.number}>0</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={{ minWidth: 30 }}>
            {code.length > 0 && (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={numberBackspace}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="backspace-outline" size={26} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>  
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  greeting: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 80,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  codeView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: 20,
    marginVertical: 100
  },
  codeEmpty: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  numbersView: {
    marginHorizontal: 80,
    gap: 60
  },
  number: {
    fontSize: 32
  }
});
export default Page

код экрана блокировки:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import * as Haptics from 'expo-haptics';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withRepeat, withSequence, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import * as LocalAuthentication from 'expo-local-authentication';
import auth from "app/(modals)/setlock";
export { auth };

const Page = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const codeLength = Array(6).fill(0);
  const router = useRouter();

  const offset = useSharedValue(0);
  const style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateX: offset.value }],
    }
  })

  const OFFSET = 20;
  const TIME = 80;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (code.length === 6) {
      if (code.join('') === auth) {
        router.replace('/map');
        setCode([]);
      } else {
        offset.value = withSequence(
          withTiming(-OFFSET, { duration: TIME / 2 }),
          withRepeat(withTiming(OFFSET, { duration: TIME }), 4, true),
          withTiming(0, { duration: TIME / 2 }),
        );
        Haptics.notificationAsync(Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Error);

        setCode([]);
      }
    }
  }, [code]);

  const onNumberPress = (number: number) => {
    Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
    setCode([...code, number]);
  };

  const numberBackspace = () => {
    Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
    setCode(code.slice(0, -1));
  };

  const onBiometricPress = async () => {
    const { success } = await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync();
    if (success) {
      router.replace('/');
    } else {
      Haptics.notificationAsync(Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.greeting}>Welcome back, Artyom</Text>

      <Animated.View style={[styles.codeView, style]}>
        {codeLength.map((_, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={[styles.codeEmpty,
            {
              backgroundColor: code[index] ? '#3D38ED' : '#D8DCE2',
            }]} />
        ))}
      </Animated.View>

      <View style={styles.numbersView}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          {[1, 2, 3].map((number) => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text key={number} style={styles.number} onPress={() => onNumberPress(number)}>
              {number}
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          {[4, 5, 6].map((number) => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text key={number} style={styles.number} onPress={() => onNumberPress(number)}>
              {number}
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          {[7, 8, 9].map((number) => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text key={number} style={styles.number} onPress={() => onNumberPress(number)}>
              {number}
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>

        <View style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBiometricPress}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='face-recognition' size={26} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onNumberPress(0)}>
            <Text style={styles.number}>0</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={{ minWidth: 30 }}>
            {code.length > 0 && (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={numberBackspace}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="backspace-outline" size={26} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>  
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  greeting: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 80,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  codeView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: 20,
    marginVertical: 100
  },
  codeEmpty: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  numbersView: {
    marginHorizontal: 80,
    gap: 60
  },
  number: {
    fontSize: 32
  }
});
export default Page


Вот есть 2 компонента. А где в них ошибка? В чем между ними разница(глазами сверять не хочется)?

пишет что ошибка в файле lock.tsx:
if (code.join('') === auth)
Это сравнение кажется непреднамеренным, поскольку типы "string" и "() => React.JSX.Element" не перекрываются.

[{
"resource": "/Users/artemmedvedev/Desktop/SpinEx-App/app/(modals)/lock.tsx",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "2367",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Это сравнение кажется непреднамеренным, поскольку типы "string" и "() => React.JSX.Element" не перекрываются.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 29,
"startColumn": 11,
"endLineNumber": 29,
"endColumn": 33
}]

Что такое auth из "app/(modals)/setlock"?

lock.tsx это код экрана блокировки

я пытлася импортировать значения введеные пользователем в переменную auth
и экспортировать его в setlock.jsx ( код экрана нового пароля )

я могу дать тебе сылку на репозиторий гит хаб может тебе станет понятней

По ссылкам лазить не буду. Все подробности должны быть в вопросе. Так все же, что такое auth? Это auth должен из файла экспортироваться. Судя по ошибке, это вообще реакт-компонент, который вы хотите сравнить со строкой. Что вообще вы пытаетесь сделать? Скорее всего вам надо данные передавать стандартными пропсами. Как это сделать: раз два

В коде экрана блокировки code.join('') === auth что это? ошибка говорит, что слева строка, а справа видимо передается React.JSX.Element
